# Python bitand (&) vs and

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, logical-and

Hi all I have this part of code:

```
for line in response.body.split("\n"):
    if line != "": 
        opg = int(line.split(" ")[2])
        opc = int(line.split(" ")[3])
        value = int(line.split(" ")[5])
        if opg==160 & opc==129:
            ret['success'] = "valore: %s" % (value)
            self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(ret))
```

I have a series of line of type

```
1362581670        2459546910990453036    156     0     30      0
```

I want to take only the line where the third and fourth element is respectively 160 and 129.
This code doesn't work. Do I have to do some casting? I think opg==160 is working to compare int with int...

Comment: Those look like tabs, not spaces- is that right?

Comment: `&` is not doing what you think its doing. Use `and`.

Comment: With the way your data is formatted, by saying `line.split(" ")` it would only split after a single space, not that tab. If this caused the problem, you should try to remove the tabs in between the data to look like `1362581670 2459546910990453036 156 0 30 0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got confused with the operators; [`and` is the correct boolean test](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), `&` is a [binary bitwise operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) instead:

```
if opg == 160 and opc == 129:
```

As a numeric operator, the `&` operator has a [higher precedence than comparison operators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), while the boolean operators have a lower precedence. The expression `opg == 160 & opc == 129` is thus interpreted as `opg == (160 & opc) == 129` instead, which is probably not what you wanted.

You can simplify your code somewhat:

```
for line in response.body.splitlines():
    if line:
        line = map(int, line.split())
        opg, opc, value = line[2], line[3], line[5]
        if opg == 160 and opc == 129:
            ret['success'] = "valore: %s" % (value)
            self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(ret))
```

Answer (score 2):

`&` is a bitwise operation.  You probably want `and`.  With integers, you *might* not think that it would make a difference

```
>>> True & False
False
>>> True & True
True
>>> False & False
False
```

However, note that `&` and `and` have [different priorities](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

```
>>> opc,opg = 160,129
>>> opc == 160 & opg == 129
False
>>> opc == 160 and opg == 129
True
```

Basically, `&` binds tighter than `==`, so `a == b & c == d` is parsed as `a == ( b & c) == d` rather than `(a == b) & (c == d)` like you wanted.

```
>>> def func1():
...     opc,opg = 160,129
...     opc == 160 & opg == 129
... 
>>> def func2():
...     opc,opg = 160,129
...     opc == 160 and opg == 129
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(func1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ((160, 129))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (opc)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (opg)

  3          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (opc)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 (160)
             18 LOAD_FAST                1 (opg)
             21 BINARY_AND          
             22 DUP_TOP             
             23 ROT_THREE           
             24 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             27 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    39
             30 LOAD_CONST               2 (129)
             33 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             36 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 41)
        >>   39 ROT_TWO             
             40 POP_TOP             
        >>   41 POP_TOP             
             42 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             45 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(func2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ((160, 129))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (opc)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (opg)

  3          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (opc)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 (160)
             18 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             21 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    33
             24 LOAD_FAST                1 (opg)
             27 LOAD_CONST               2 (129)
             30 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
        >>   33 POP_TOP             
             34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             37 RETURN_VALUE
```

As pointed out by Hoopdady, you also aren't splitting your string correctly.  `line.split()` or `line.split(None)` will split on consecutive runs of whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `line.split()` instead of `line.split(" ")`. That way it handles any type of whitespace. If those aren't just spaces, you'll get some weird results, which may be what's happening.

Comment: Nope, the `int()` call ignores the extra whitespace.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yeah, but `"1_____2".split(" ")[1]` doesn't even give you something "`int`able" (where `_` are representing spaces)