# if else Conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

The problem is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AdaL.png)

My solution:

```
n= int(input())
if n%2==0:
    if (n >=2 & n<=5):
        print("Not Weird")
    elif n >=6 & n<=20:
        print("Weird")
    else:
        print ("Not Weired")
else:
    print ("Weird")
```

Now, if I enter 18 then it should be printed `"Weird"`. But it is showing `"Not Weird"`.

I am not getting where the problem of my code is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python bitand (&) vs and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251121/python-bitand-vs-and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `&` is the bitwise and operation.
You need *logical AND*, instead, and it is done by means of `and` keyword.

Just replace `&` with `and`:

```
n= int(input())
if n%2==0:
    if (n >=2 and n<=5):    #modified here!
        print("Not Weird")
    elif n >=6 and n<=20:   #modified here!
        print("Weird")
    else:
        print ("Not Weird")
else:
    print ("Weird")
```

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
if n >= 2 and n <= 5:
elif n >= 6 and n <= 20:
```

instead of binary and

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the [bitwise and](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm) `&` instead of the logical operator `and`.

```
n= int(input())

if n%2 == 0:
    if n >=2 and n<=5:   # Changed condition
        print("Not Weird")
    elif n >=6 and n<=20:   # Changed condition
        print("Weird")
    else:
        print ("Not Weired")

else:
    print ("Weird")
```